# Connecting crypto wallet apps with 3rd party apps

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, metamask, wallet, wallet-connect

Is there any current method to connect a crypto wallet ( Android app) like metamask with another crypto app (Android)?
If I click connect wallet ( metamask) on my crypto based Android dapp then it must automatically open the metamask app and  prompt authentication to connect wallet for transaction

Answer (score 0):

wallet connect's dapp library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/react-native-dapp can be used to connect dApp with metamask wallet (List of wallets available on current device & which are supported by wallet connect will be displayed)